# PHP API track Twilio Responses

Tags: php, twilio

i'm working on an web app that has a message thread within and each time a new message is sent to a person a SMS is sent to that person, so what we want to do is to include the person's response to that SMS, lets say A sends a message to B, B receives both an email and a SMS, if B responses to A via the phone we need to be able to add that response to the thread. Is there a way to add additional information when you send a message using the API?

The sending SMS code looks like this:

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($accountSID,$authToken);
$sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage("TwilioNumber",$toNumber,$message);
```

So, is there a way in which i could add some type of information to track this SMS thread, so when i get the response to the Request URL i could actually know that this message is being sent from B as a response from the message sent from A.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately SMS does not have the idea of "meta-data" so there is nothing you can include that would tell you a message is in "response" to another message, but there are some solutions here.

You could create a convention of commands that are included in the actual body of the text message that tell you the message is ins response to a specific thread.  But thats not super user friendly.

You're best bet is probably going to using multiple phone numbers and phone number tracking.

For example, when A sends the message to B you'll need to store both of their phone numbers along with the Twilio phone number that is receiving and relaying those messages.  This allows you to map the two users together in a "thread" even though they are not directly texting each other.

But what happens when A wants to have seperate thread with both B and C?  With a single Twilio phone number how do you know what thread to route their message to?  The simplest way to allow this is to have multiple phone numbers.  To send a message to B, A sends to 555-555-5555, to send a message to C, A sends to 555-555-6666.  In this scenario you might think about buying a pool of numbers that you can draw from and recycle so you don't have to continuously buy new numbers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks man! i really appreciate it, we are waiting for the client to buy the phone numbers.